# I'm trying to display data from MySQL onto a PHP page that contains a table but I can't get the info to display inside the table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to display rows from a mysql database in a table but I can't get the PHP to display in the html.  This is my code:

```
    <?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die("no connection");
$db_select=mysql_select_db("smqr",$connection)
or die("no connection to db");

    $query= ("SELECT * FROM seafood");
    $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

    while
    ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)):
     $recipe=$row['recipe'];
     $usrtext=$row['usrtext']; 
     $usrtxt=$row['usrtxt'];


    endwhile;
     ?>

  <body bgcolor="#ffccff">
  <table align="center"  width="780" height="100%"  bgcolor="lightgrey" border="1">   
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th height="220">
    <img src="seafoods.jpg" width="100%" height="220" /></th></tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Recipe Name <p>
    <? echo "$recipe" ?></p></th></tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Ingrediants and Measurements
    <p><? echo $usrtext ?></p></th></tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Instructions
    <p> <? echo $usrtxt ?></p></th>
    </tr>
```

I thought I had to echo the table in the while loop and I tried echo table but it didn't work so I tried to add PHP in the html which is what I have posted. When I echo `$recipe` before endwhile it will display the info but I need it in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Check if php short tags is enabled in your php settings file. if not you can't use `<?` you must use `<?php`

example:

```
<?php echo $usrtext ?>
```

Also The while loop ended before the display table. end the while loop after display that is at the end.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<table align="center"  width="780" height="100%"  bgcolor="lightgrey" border="1">   
  <tr>
    <td>Recipe Name </td>
    <td>Ingrediants and Measurements</td>
    <td>Instructions</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("no connection");
  $db_select=mysql_select_db("smqr",$connection) or die("no connection to db");

    $query= ("SELECT * FROM seafood");
    $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $recipe=$row['recipe'];
     $usrtext=$row['usrtext']; 
     $usrtxt=$row['usrtxt'];
     ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$recipe?></td>
    <td><?=$usrtext?></td>
    <td><?=$usrtxt?></td>
  </tr>
 <?php
    }// End while
 ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code like this by adding

```
<?php ?> instead of <? ?>



<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die("no connection");
$db_select=mysql_select_db("test",$connection)
or die("no connection to db");

    $query= ("SELECT * FROM profile");
    $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

    while
    ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)):
    $recipe=$row['recipe'];
 $usrtext=$row['usrtext']; 
 $usrtxt=$row['usrtxt'];


    endwhile;
     ?>

  <body bgcolor="#ffccff">
  <table align="center"  width="780" height="100%"  bgcolor="lightgrey" border="1">   
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th height="220">
    <img src="seafoods.jpg" width="100%" height="220" /></th></tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Recipe Name <p>
    <?php echo "$recipe" ?></p></th></tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Ingrediants and Measurements
    <p><?php echo $usrtext ?></p></th></tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Instructions
    <p> <?php echo $usrtxt ?></p></th>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

$recipe, $usrtext and $usrtxt are all defined within the local scope of your while loop so they won't exist after "endwhile;" anymore

```
<?
//define variables outside the while loop
$recipe;
$usrtext;
$usrtxt;
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)):
   $recipe=$row['recipe'];
   $usrtext=$row['usrtext']; 
   $usrtxt=$row['usrtxt'];
endwhile;
 ?>

<body bgcolor="#ffccff">
<table align="center"  width="780" height="100%"  bgcolor="lightgrey" border="1">   
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th height="220">
      <img src="seafoods.jpg" width="100%" height="220" />
    </th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>
       Recipe Name 
       <p> <? echo $recipe ?></p>
     </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <th>
     Ingrediants and Measurements
     <p><? echo $usrtext ?></p>
   </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>
      Instructions
        <p> <? echo $usrtxt ?></p>
    </th>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You code contains some bad stuff, first of all, you shouldn't use `<? ?>`, I don't even know if that's valid somewhere. Use either `<?= ?>` or `<?php echo ?>` (but use `<?php` instead, because it's more compatible.

Secondary, it would be a good idea to use PDO library istead of MySQL, it's safer, easyer, more flexible and more compatible, use [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF8hoPj-1bc) tutorial.

Now, you can try this:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
        or die("no connection");
    $db_select=mysql_select_db("smqr",$connection)
        or die("no connection to db");

    $query= ("SELECT * FROM seafood");
    $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
?>
<table>
<?php 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)): // everything between "while():" and "endwhile;" will be outputted in a cycle
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['recipe']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['usrtext']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo  $row['usrtxt']; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

this is called inline coding

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
...

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

  <table align="center" width="780" height="100%" bgcolor="lightgrey" border="1">   
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th height="220">
          <img src="seafoods.jpg" width="100%" height="220" />
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Recipe Name <p>
          <?php echo $row['recipe']; ?></p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Ingrediants and Measurements
        <p><?php echo $row['usrtxt']; ?></p>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Instructions
        <p><?php echo $row['usrtxt']; ?></p>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: don't you whant to use 
<php while () : ?>
do something
<php? endwhile; ?>

Comment: I used this system a while ago, now I'm using PDO ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your query result returns **more than one row**, then most probably you are looking for something like this:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("no connection");
    $db_select  = mysql_select_db("smqr", $connection) or die("no connection to db");
    $query      = "SELECT * FROM seafood";
    $result     = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<body bgcolor="#ffccff">
    <table align="center" width="780" bgcolor="lightgrey" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Recipe Name</th>
                <th>Ingrediants and Measurements</th>
                <th>Instructions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['recipe']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['usrtext']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['usrtxt']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**Note:** If the above code works for you, carefully follow what changes I made on your code. Hope this will help you learn writing better code. :)